# Swift 3 Getting nil value when I shouldn't be - MKMapView

Tags: swift

Below is my code to placing an annotation on a Map View. I'm getting a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value error". I do not know why my annotation value is giving a nil value.

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewcontroller: UIViewController {

    var itemStore: ItemStore!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("test")

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.71304, longitude: -74.0072)
        annotation.title = "Test"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation) //error here
    }
```

Comment: `mapView` is `nil`.

Comment: In general, if the compiler says you are wrong you should trust it. The engineers who created the compiler are smarter than most of us.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Except this isn't a compiler message. This is a runtime error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably `annotation` is ok, just check that you had connected `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!` with storyboard object.

Comment: Why do I need to connect it with a storyboard object? I'm just loading it on the load of the view.

Comment: @LukeNoel cuz you're using `@IBOutlet`. If you don't use Storyboard, then make you `MKMapView` programmatically.

Comment: @LukeNoel Where do you expect the `MKMapView` object to be created from? All you have is an empty reference. Either you have to instantiate it yourself, or hook it up to a story board that will instantiate it for you